# Change zoom rate for Show Active and Local View

Tags: 3d-view

I really like the functions Show Active (.) and Local View (Numpad /). They zoom in on either the selected object, or the selection in Edit Mode.

However, I find they zoom in a little too much for my liking. I was wondering if there's a way to change this? See my screenshot as an example. I'd like to see the whole object when zoomed in, without it being cut-off at the top and bottom.

[image]